# Saving images locally in windows phone 8.1 universal app

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want to download and save(cache) images locally in windows phone 8.1 universal app. so that if Phone is offline I can show users images(avatars) in ListView.

1. What is the best way of saving images to local storage(should I use local storage or I use sqlite as i am using sqlite to store user's other information)?
2. How can I save (download) images to local store?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a great extension by Q42 in their Q42.WinRT framework called ImageExtensions.cs

You use it on normal Image objects in XAML, but instead of setting the Source of the Image, you set the ImageExtensions.CacheUri.

```
<Image q42controls:ImageExtensions.CacheUri="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico" />
```

q42controls is just a namespace added on top of the XAML page

```
xmlns:q42controls="using:Q42.WinRT.Controls"
```

When the image is loaded, it's automatically cached!

Comment: Thanks igrali. I will try this extension

Comment: Thanks for the answer @igrali, this extension rocks! By the way it is even possible to specify a default image while loading using the usual `Source` of the image