# Expire time for locally cached images on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am extending a previously asked question about [caching images locally in windows phone 8.1 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797604/saving-images-locally-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app)

I am using ImageExtension from the [Q42.WinRT framework](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT) as suggested in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24799630/1000257) to cache images on the device, but I still have an additional requirement to set an expire time on the cached image, mainly to avoid using storage for images that won't be used anymore.

My current code is:

```
...
xmlns:q42Controls="using:Q42.WinRT.Controls"
...

<!-- Event Image
     Source set to default image
     Extension for using image cache-->
<Image Stretch="UniformToFill"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       Source="/Assets/default_image.png"
       q42Controls:ImageExtensions.CacheUri="{Binding Image.Url}"/>
```

Is there any way to indicate an expire time for the images being cached by the framework?

Comment: It looks like the current implementation ( https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT/blob/master/Q42.WinRT/Controls/ImageExtensions.cs ) doesn't give you any help with this! So my guess, log a request on the github site. Or try to implement it yourself?

Comment: Thanks. I indeed made the same question on [a github issue for the project](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT/issues/15). It seems I will need to implement a custom functionality as you suggest.

Comment: They are also very active on twitter so maybe ask them there too https://twitter.com/q42

Answer (score 0):

There was definitely no functionality to delete old images so I implemented the change and made a [pull request](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT/pull/18) to integrate it in the [Q42.WinRT library](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT).
Version 1.3.0.42 [now available on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Q42.WinRT/) has the change available.

On app initialization (App.xaml.cs in my case) I added the following line:

```cs
await WebDataCache.Clear(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
```

This deletes all the files which haven't modified for the given time span.

Comment: Nice one!! Hope they add it